# SAPUI5 OData 401 (Unauthorized) + No Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header

Tags: odata, sapui5, same-origin-policy, http-status-code-401

I work in SAP Web IDE to develop an SAPUI5 application which uses OData Service CUAN_IMPORT_SRV.

I start by defining the OData Model this way:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("https://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/CUAN_IMPORT_SRV/", true, "UNAME", "PASSWORD");
```

Username and Password can access the data and do read + create operations on Hybris Marketing. This is tested with Postman.

However, when I try to test my application with Test Fiori Launchpad, I get this error message when executing the OData call:

[image: F12 Console Error]

Concering this topic, I read some other posts and tried to edit the URL to

```
proxy/https/host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/CUAN_IMPORT_SRV/
```

...but this results in 404 Not Found.

Since I use Chrome as Browser, I disabled web security as I read in other posts. This did not work. That's why I tried [this Chrome AddOn](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en). As a result, I got this error log:

[image: F12 Console after using AddOn]

What more can I try to solve this issue?
Thank you for any advice!

---

Tried configuring destination in Cloud Platform:

[image: destination configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Web IDE does not allow Cross Origin access.
In order access your ODATA service from Web IDE, you have to use Cloud Connector.

Cloud connector will create a ternel between AP Cloud platform and your ODATA Service Gateway System.

Follow these steps:
https://blogs.sap.com/2014/06/22/how-to-configure-an-external-gw-system-with-sap-river-rde/

[image]

Comment: Hi Piyush. Thank you for the feedback. Is there any alternative for using Cloud connector (e.g. using Eclipse / Web IDE personal edition)? I think we did not configure Cloud Connector and I'm not in the position to do that.

Comment: If you are developing for internal use, then i can suggest multiple ways.
But if you wish to deploy it on Cloud, then you have to create a entry in Destination tab under connectivity (I am attaching a screensht in my post). (It's not neccesary to configure Cloud Connector On premise if your IP is exposed)

Comment: It's just for internal use. I read something about ReverseProxy. What else can you suggest?

I just tried adding the destination but since the service is not public available and the Cloud Connector is not configured, this is not possible (Failure reason: "peer not authenticated").

Comment: You can share me your screenshot of error in you post.
If internal use, you can develop on Ecipse and in you chrome use prluginn: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en
For deveopment and you can deploy your application into your R/3 system as a BP application itself

Comment: @ChrisHackb seems you are not authorized. So yu have develop using ecipse and deploy you applicaton on R/3 system using ecipse.

Comment: I updated the post with the screenshot. It is planned to deploy the application to ABAP system as BSP application at a later point. Right now I need to test it first.

Comment: Develop it using Eclipse or Web IDE offline version